# Linq Expression property type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq expression defined as follows:

```
private void GetMyPropertyType<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    // some code
    ----- HERE -----
}
```

which is called as

```
GetMyPropertyType<SomeType>(x => x.Age);
```

Now I want to know what the type is of "Age" at the position marked as "HERE".
The closest I've gotten is:"

```
expression.Body.Member.ToString()
```

which returns the value `Int64 Age` that I can then split and only take the first part of. The problem however is that I want to get the full path (`System.Int64`) which it only returns for certain types (like `String`).
Am I missing a completely obvious method? Or should I be doing it in this very ugly fashion?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `expression.Body.Member` wouldn't compile, as far as I can tell... but have you tried `expression.Body.Type`? But the fact that you're using `Func<T, object>` doesn't help here, as there'll be a conversion.

Comment: Yes, @JonSkeet, I did, but it returns either "System.String", "System.Byte[]" or "System.Object" for everything - even an `int` gets returned as `System.Object`

Comment: What would you suggest as function instead? `private void GetMyPropertyType(Expression<object> expression)`?

Comment: Why do you want to know the type?  Just curious since needing to know the type may indicate that generics are not the right design choice.

Comment: @DStanley What I/we as a company are doing is encrypting certain columns in our database. To do that I am overriding their implementation of the NHibernate's AddEncryptedProperty to also generate an SQL update query that encrypts the data that is already in the existing database. I hope this makes some sense to you :P (Baiscally: we have a database with a few hundred thousand records and no encryption. We are going to make sure every new piece of data is encrypted, but we also want to replace all current values with their encrypted counterparts, for which we have to make these queries).

Comment: @DStanley Do note that none of these choices were mine to make - I was instructed to do so and am just doing as I'm being told.

Comment: @Voidpaw no worries - I just see questions frequently that "decompose" generic arguments to get their type in order to cal different methods when overloads would be a safer design choice.

Comment: @DStanley Yeh, fair point - I can see that you were asking about it for that reason; it might teach someone a thing or two about generics after all :). Thanks for showing interest, it's good to see that people are still willing to teach and help out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Expression.Type` to find out the static type of the expression. However, because you've got `Expression<Func<T, object>>` you've actually got a conversion expression around the property expression, so you need to remove that first. Here's some sample code which works for the simple cases I've tried:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ShowMemberType<Person>(p => p.Age);
        ShowMemberType<Person>(p => p.Name);
    }

    static void ShowMemberType<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body;
        // Unwrap the conversion to object, if there is one.
        if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", body.Type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It works for almost everything (Only the nullable ones give a weird result, but I can add a check for that to fix it).

Comment: Going a bit further, you can get a lot more info from the "PropertyInfo" object hidden in the expression. Extract it like so: 

        `var memberExpression = body as MemberExpression;`


        `var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;`


        `Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", propertyInfo.PropertyType);`

Comment: @Moeri Good call, but I've used the solution that Jon Skeet gave me because it gives me all I will need for this project. I will keep it in mind though, and if you submit it as a response then I'll be sure to upvote it so others can learn from this.